# How to get LanguageModel JS File?

Tags: javascript, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have been using PocketSphinx.js for speech recognition on my website. I have Downloaded language model file (.dmp). But their code uses JS file for Language model. I dont know where to get JS file. Help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, you can convert dmp file to js and load it afterwards, see the section https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js/#i-embedding-the-files-into-one-large-javascript-file. Something like

```
$ cmake -DEMSCRIPTEN=1 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path_to_emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -LM_BASE=/lm/dmp/folder/name -LM_FILES=model.dmp ..
```

Also check an alternative section https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js#ii-package-model-files-outside-the-main-javascript where you can do:

```
# python .../emscripten/tools/file_packager.py .../pocketsphinx.js/build/pocketsphinx.js --embed model.dmp --js-output=model.dmp.js
```

Overall, you need smaller models, big models from CMUSPHINX downloads are too large